# How do I know if a new dryer will fit? Existing base/floor vent and nearby doorframe

Tags: dryer, measurement

Our existing washer and dryer need to go, but the space they occupy is a bit limited.

The main issue is depth - the existing washer and dryer are Frigidaire AES7000ES and ATF7000FS. In the current setup, with a bottom/base vent, the main shell extends ~28" from the wall (the door adds another 1")  Reading the docs for this dryer it seems that it's 27" deep not counting the door.

The primary problem with the dryer is the door to the room -- the dryer as situated is only 4" from the door frame (3" if you count the added depth of the door, but that's not all the way to the edge).

[image: existing dryer]

[image: existing dryer measurements]

Nobody really sells equivalently sized appliances at this point -- they are either much smaller or larger.  I'm looking at LG replacements - for the dryer, the DLE3400W -- the specs say 30" deep.  That has me concerned for 2 reasons.  First, I can't find detailed measurements for this dryer, to know what they are measuring when they say 30".  Second, I can't find detailed placement of where the bottom vent is.  The existing vent tubing is in a fixed spot in the floor, which will affect the placement of the dryer and how far it might extend outward.  Or is there some flexibility when installing the base/bottom venting?

I feel stupid here.  I have this tight spot and don't want to find out after ordering and delivery that it's not going to work in the space.

Comment: It’s called a tape measure but one and measure.

Comment: I have one and I've measured -- the problem is: how do I account for the bottom vent of the new dryer?  Is that a fixed thing or is it something with some wiggle room?  I can't find any details from LG, so I'm wondering if someone who's done more installs of dryers (esp with the bottom vent) than me (0) can speak to whether or not I have any flexibility there.

Comment: because if the front extends to 32" i'm ok but if it's 33" then it'll hit the door.  So a 30" depth gives me almost no margin of error.

Comment: According to the drawing it looked like it could be side exit many can do either. If the company or sales team is not helpful go to a brand that will assist. You have a dryer and can measure how much room is needed for the pipe use that measurement we cannot see your connection just the front.

Comment: The DLE3400W Owner's Manual shows how to configure it for rear, side or bottom venting. It does not have reference drawings with dimensions and does not appear to offer any means of adjusting the vent locations, e.g. moving the bottom vent a little to the left. Is there a friendly local merchant with a well stocked showroom where you could inspect and measure?

Comment: If you can find the dryer at your local big-box store, borrow one of their tape measures, pull the dryer from its display spot and start measuring. If an employee asks, just tell 'em you can't buy it without knowing if it will fit, but that if it fits you're buying.